How to create a pure XML sitemap instead of wordpress's XSL/HTML sitemap?
I'm using wordpress 6.1.1 trying to create a sitemap. When I go to wp-sitemap.xml I see an HTML document which shows everything as a table.
If I view source, I see the xml file like I was expecting. I guess there's some way that browser is being checked and returning HTML instead of XML. I want to return raw XML always so that if I look at this in the browser I will see something that starts with:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

This is what I already see when I view source. I tried adding these filters to functions.php:
add_filter('wp_sitemaps_stylesheet_index', '__return_false');
add_filter('wp_sitemaps_stylesheet_sitemap', '__return_false');

But they don't seem to do anything. Do I need to rebuild the sitemap somehow to see the new changes?

The browser is not "returning HTML", it's just rendering XML like a web page. What you are describing is rendering XML as plain text. That would require to send a MIME type text/plain. But then it wouldn't be  XML anymore. You really don't want that for your sitemap.
